# Registration Tools Bug to Sign in

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I have a problem with the "registration tools" on my Windows.

I launch Windows Phone 7 Solution for deploy a new version in my phone (Nokia Lumia 920), but I've reset him (with the amber update), and I have to re-register on my dev account...

No problem. I launch Registration tools , ans The "Suscribe" button appear (My Phone appear too on the Windows Folders...)

When I click on the subscribe button, the "Sign In "Windows appear, but remains empty... I don't want to set my login/password and validate for subscribe my phone...

I don't want to subscribe my phone on my developer account withmy laptop, ( I have already try with reboot Windows...) And I don't want to re-install all me developer environement...

The "registration Tools" has already worked on my Laptop, I have no ideas why it bug today.. (I have no install the Windows 8.1 preview version).

Do you have the same Problem?

And do You have an idea for re-install just the "registration tools"? or to subrscibe my phone on my dev account without this "registration tools"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today, I re-start my computer and the developper tools works...

(I was aready restart my computer before ?!)

For people has a problem with the developer tools. I find [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (in a "Troubleshooting registration" part).

In this part, the most likely error, when the 'Login windows' is empty is this:

```
• Are both the computer and the phone connected to the Internet? On your computer,
  make sure that your web browser does not have Work offline enabled. Also, you cannot
  connect through a proxy server that redirects to a login page; for example, in a 
  hotel or an airport.
```

Answer (score 0):

To Register with developer account, make sure that you have already installed Zune latest version.. and your device is getting connected properly.

Comment: Thx, but Zune is Installed. And, it's nessecary just for Windows Phone 7 Devices, With Windows Phone 8, computer (and Visual Studio) find the device without Zune.